# concatenate two input to one tensor keras expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 6 but received input with shape [5, 288, 288, 3]

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, image-processing, keras

I have two data inputs with the same shape for my U-net model.
I have 2 (or more) images representing the same object but are using different types of cameras/images, e.g. night vision, thermal, rgb, etc. In such case I would just stack all the layers on top of each other and treat them as a "single image".

I tried :

```
X_train = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([X_train, X_train2])
```

X_train shape is (288,288,3)

X_train2 shape is (288,288,3)

The result of the concatenation gives me a concatenated image with shape (288,288,6).So that's why i set the input shape of model to (288,288,6)

**My Code is as below :**

```
import cv2

from keras import backend as K
import tensorflow as tf
import os
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm
from skimage.io import imread, imshow
# from keras.preprocessing.image import cv2
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
#from keras.callbacks import ReduceLROnPlateau
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ReduceLROnPlateau

from skimage.transform import resize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import keras
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

!ls /content/drive/

from keras.models import load_model

from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
from keras.models import load_model




X_train = np.zeros((1, 288, 288, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

Y_train = np.zeros((1, 288, 288, 12),
                   dtype=np.uint8)  # what we are trying to predict ), IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDHT, 3, 1
X_val = np.zeros((1, 288, 288, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

Y_val = np.zeros((1, 288, 288, 12),
                   dtype=np.uint8)  # what we are trying to predict ), IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDHT, 3, 1


X_train=np.concatenate([X_train, X_train], axis = -1)




inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input((288, 288, 6))
print('X_trononononononnnonono',inputs.shape)

smooth = 1.
s = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x / 255)(inputs)
c1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(
    s)  # Kernelsize : start with some weights initial value
c1 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(c1)
c1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(
    c1)  # Kernelsize : start with some weights initial value
p1 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D((2, 2))(c1)

c2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(
    p1)  # Kernelsize : start with some weights initial value
c2 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(c2)
c2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(
    c2)  # Kernelsize : start with some weights initial value
p2 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D((2, 2))(c2)

c3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(
    p2)  # Kernelsize : start with some weights initial value
c3 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(c3)
c3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(
    c3)  # Kernelsize : start with some weights initial value
p3 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D((2, 2))(c3)

c4 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(
    p3)  # Kernelsize : start with some weights initial value
c4 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(c4)
c4 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(
    c4)  # Kernelsize : start with some weights initial value
p4 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D((2, 2))(c4)


c5 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(1024, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(
    p4)  # Kernelsize : start with some weights initial value
c5 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(c5)
c5 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(1024, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(
    c5)  # Kernelsize : start wi


u6 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(512, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(c5)
u6 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([u6, c4])
c6 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(u6)
c6 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(c6)
c6 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c6)

u7 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(256, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(c6)
u7 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([u7, c3])
c7 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (2, 2), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(u7)
c7 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(c7)
c7 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c7)

u8 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(128, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(c7)
u8 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([u8, c2])
c8 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (2, 2), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(u8)
c8 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(c8)
c8 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c8)

u9 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(64, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(c8)
u9 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([u9, c1], axis=3)
c9 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(u9)
c9 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(c9)
c9 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c9)



outputs = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(12, (1, 1), activation='softmax')(c9)#, activity_regularizer=l1(0.0001)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[outputs])

#model = unet_v1_deeper()
cc = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, amsgrad=False,decay = 1e-6) #epsilon=1e-07,,decay = 1e-6
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.001, decay=1e-6)
opt2 = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.1, momentum=0.9, nesterov=False)
de =  tf.keras.optimizers.Adadelta(learning_rate=0.1, rho=0.95)


from keras.losses import categorical_crossentropy
def focal_loss(target, output, gamma=2):
    output /= K.sum(output, axis=-1, keepdims=True)
    eps = K.epsilon()
    output = K.clip(output, eps, 1. - eps)
    return -K.sum(K.pow(1. - output, gamma) * target * tf.math.log(output), #Kf.log
                  axis=-1)


   # return (1-ytrue[:, :, :, 0])*categorical_crossentropy(ytrue, ypred)


from keras import backend as K






model.compile(optimizer= cc, loss=focal_loss,
              metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])  # metrics =[dice_coeff] model.summary(),sample_weight_mode="temporal"
#tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=2, monitor='val_loss')
model.summary()
print(X_train.shape)
checkpointer = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint('model350epk.h5', verbose = 1, save_best_only = True)



history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, validation_data=(X_val,Y_val), batch_size=5,epochs = 2,shuffle=True) #,callbacks = callbacks
```

I'm getting this error :

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv2d is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 6 but received input with shape [5, 288, 288, 3]
```

Comment: Can you please tell me your output shape?

Comment: @BobbyOcean my output shape is 288,288,3

Comment: It is highly recommended that your provide minimal working code that can actually be run. I have copied and pasted your code, but then I have to change or guess various variables to get it to run. You can create fake data by setting X_train = np.zeros((100,288,288,10)). Can you please edit your code so that a reproducible error can be found when copied and pasted?

Comment: @BobbyOcean I added all code. but it is very ambiguous that's why I didn't want to add it first

Comment: @BobbyOcean Any idea Please?

Comment: Friend, it is very hard to follow what you are doing with all this code. A minimal working example is intended to be a single script that works and produces the error. Your question is very unstructured with code at the bottom, and the top, then in the middle. You don't need all this code, you can replace things (like your data) with some np.zeros arrays. I don't need all the code for your data, unless that is where the error is. But if that is where the error is, I don't need your entire model. Have you tried running model.summary() to see what tensorflow thinks your inputs and outputs are?

Comment: @BobbyOcean I'm really sorry. I replace my code with a new simple code that represent my error hope you will understand it. yes I tried using summary my input is 288,288,3 and my output is 288,288,12 and 12 represent the number of classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `fit` function expects a numpy array. You should use numpy `concatenate`

```
import numpy as np
X_train = np.concatenate((X_train, X_train2), axis = -1)
print(X_train.shape)
```

Also make sure `X_train` has shape (None, 288,288,6)

You're still getting the error because even though you fixed the `X_train`, you didn't fix the `X_val`. So, do the same `numpy concatenation` for `X_val`.

```
X_train = np.concatenate([X_train, X_train], axis = -1)
X_val = np.concatenate([X_val, X_val], axis = -1) # you missed this
print(X_train.shape)
print(Y_train.shape)
print(X_val.shape)
print(Y_val.shape)

history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, validation_data=(X_val,Y_val), batch_size=5,epochs = 2,shuffle=True) #,callbacks = callbacks
```

Comment: np.concatenate gives me this shape (640, 320, 3) and I get this error :                       x sizes: 1752 and y sizes: 876
Please provide data which shares the same first dimension.

Comment: Did you use axis = -1? Also, where is your batch dimension? Post the relevant code where you make these arrays.

Comment: Thanks for replay.Sorry I forget axis= -1, but adding it gives me the same error. I'm gonna add my code to the post

Comment: np.concatenate is used for ARRAYS. You are using TENSORS, you must use a tensor concatenate. What you have is correct above, using a tensorflow concatenate

Comment: @BobbyOcean thanks for your replay. the error comes after the first epoch finished. What should I change?

Comment: https://keras.io/models/sequential/ read the documentation first. How's he passing tensors to the model in the first place?

Comment: Before fit function, what's the shape of X_train and Y_train? Add that to the question.

Comment: Things are changing so fast and being edited it is hard to keep up with what is know from the OP.

Comment: @ZabirAlNazi That's true true but also when using concatenation with numpy it gives me the same error is this due to the channel value = 6 ? or Y_train shape ( 288,288,3)?

Comment: I added more details in my post

Comment: @ZabirAlNazi Any idea Please?

Comment: Sorry, but clean your code up. Use dummy data so it's reproducible and the error can be tested in my system. Then people will be able to help.

Comment: @ZabirAlNazi I'm really sorry. I replace my code with a new simple code that represent my error hope you will understand it.

Comment: You forgot to change the `X_val` concatenation, check the updated answer and put the code before fit.

Comment: Can we concatenate more then 2 image I will add a post and if you can answer I will upvote for you

Comment: Ask a separate question, asking repeated question in a single post will get your question closed.

Comment: I added a separate question please check it in this link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61648869/can-we-concatenate-more-then-two-data-to-one-tensor]