# can we concatenate more then two data to one tensor

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I have three numpy array that contains my data.

```
X_train = np.zeros((1, 288, 288, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

X_train2 = np.zeros((1, 288, 288, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

X_train3 = np.zeros((1, 288, 288, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
```

Using np.concatenate I can concatenate two image to one tensor as below :

```
X_train2=np.concatenate([X_train, X_train2], axis = -1)
```

I want to concatenate multiple image X_train and X_train2 and X_train3 to one tensor is it possible using numpy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can concatenate as many numpy array as you want.

```
X_train_final = np.concatenate([X_train, X_train2, X_train3], axis = -1)
```

is valid and will give you an array where, the last dimension will be 3 times as in the original array. You can continue this way for as many arrays as you likee.

Read the documentation: https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html